# Optimal basis set of Gaussian functions for describing a quantum system

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, physics, change-of-basis, complete-spaces

Copy from here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285044/optimal-basis-set-of-gaussian-functions-for-describing-a-quantum-system

This question arose during the discussion of the previous questions: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284809/why-does-the-minimum-eigenvalue-change-dramatically-when-one-basis-function-is-a#284841 and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284910/finding-excited-states-using-the-condition-of-wave-functions-orthogonality

Brief description of the problem:

Consider the following system with the Hamiltonian: $H=-\frac{1}{2}\Delta-\frac{1}{r}+\frac{25}{8}\rho^2-5/2$, where $r=(\rho,z,\phi)$ is a coordinate in the cylindrical system. Physically, this Hamiltonian describes a hydrogen atom in a magnetic field equal to 5 (in dimensionless units).
In order to solve this problem by the matrix method, it is necessary to choose a set of basis functions. To describe ground and excited states with the z component of the angular momentum m = 0 (1s, 2s, 3d (m = 0), 3s ...), a Gaussian basis set is well suited. Such basis functions have the following form: $\psi_j=e^{-b_{j} z^2}e^{-a_{j} \rho^2}$, where $a_{j}$ and $b_{j}$ are parameters. The task is reduced to the correct finding of parameters.

The parameters describing the ground state (1s) with high accuracy were found in this work (see here https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.05553 or here https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/147/24/244108/195534/Accurate-and-balanced-anisotropic-Gaussian-type). But the basis presented in this article does not describe excited states (2s, 3d (m = 0), 3s ...) well, since there are not enough basis functions to describe them. The basis set parameters presented in this article has a complex structure, so increasing the basis set functions in this case is a difficult task.

It seems that a more general way to find the basis set of parameters is presented in this article (see here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q74hAn0UAdNd8DtPkoCsdYPkr61-xhr2/view?usp=sharing or here https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/pssb.2220930140). The sets of parameters that the authors use are geometric progressions: 
$\alpha_j=\alpha_{j-1}(\frac{\alpha_N}{\alpha_1})^{1/(N-1)}$

$\beta_j=\alpha_{j-1}(\frac{\beta_M}{\beta_1})^{1/(M-1)}$, 
where $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_N$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_M$ are the first and the last parameters. About finding these parameters, the authors write the following: "the parameters $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_N$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_M$ were varied in a four dimensional optimization search which minimized the sum of the eigen-values of interest" and "We have performed the calculations presented in this paper with a basis with ten Gaussians in the $\rho$ direction and twelve Gaiissians in the z direction, for a total of 120 different basis functions.". I really don't understand what that means?

Energy values from the articles: 
ground state (1s) = - 1.3793 (exact value = -1.380398866427)
the first excited state (2s) = -0.19335 (exact value = -0.193746709717)
the second excited state (3d (m=0)) = -0.07365 
the third excited state (3s) = -0.03835

All these states should have the same structure of the basis set function ($\psi_j=e^{-b_{j} z^2}e^{-a_{j} \rho^2}$) due to the m=0 (the z component of the angular momentum).

I have a few questions: 
I really can't understand what the authors mean in varied optimization search of the parameters $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_N$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_M$, could you please explain to me what that means?

Why do the parameters ($\alpha_1$, $\alpha_N$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_M$) have different indexes, shouldn't their number be the same? Since they are paired in the basis function.

I would be glad to any comments on solving the problem.

I would like to draw attention to the fact that to get the energy from the Aldrich, C., & Greene, R. L article it's needed the value from the table 1 to subtract the field value and divide by 2 (this is due to the fact that the authors of this article do not take into account the spin). For example for 2s state: value from the table 1 for magnetic field = 5 is equal 4.6133 so the energy of the 2s state = (4.6133 - 5)/2 = -0,19335